# Menu toggle working on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Menu toggle working on second click. If it is opened sometimes it goes away. It is not consistent.

```
f("#smt, #smp .s-panel--close").on("click", function(s) {
    s.preventDefault();
    A.toggleClass("sidemenu-opened")
});
f("#mmt, #main-nav-mobile .s-panel--close").on("click", function(s) {
    s.preventDefault();
    A.toggleClass("mm-opened")
});
f(".bs-docs-example").each(function(s, K) {
    var J = f(K),
        L = '<a href="#" class="togglecode"></a>';
    if (J.next().is("pre")) {
        J.addClass("withcode");
        J.append(L);
        J.find(".togglecode").on("click", function(M) {
            M.preventDefault();
            J.toggleClass("opened")
        })
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
 <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="smt" class="headericon mobilenav-icon"><span></span></a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Where is `A` defined?

Comment: I have included the HTML code. Do U need the complete markup?

Comment: The link is [link](http://mediamax.co.in/suhasini_1) . It is confidential but I am sharing it here. fingers crossed!

Comment: if you can paste in only "relevant" HTML, CSS, JS, that will be great.

Comment: Are you writing click event for this class headericon mobilenav-icon

Comment: if this write for that class write click event for li not an-gar tag

Comment: i am writing click event for the id smt

Comment: i hv gvn html,js vlin pls help me out